# What to do? My user defined input is not allowing me to input a value

Tags: plsql, ampersand, defined

I wrote a procedure that is supposed to allow the input of a username and password and if successful it should proc a timestamp of the login. Problem is is that the code seems to skip the &username altogether and moves on to the next user defined entry which is the &pass in the code. This is my code:  **ECHO IS ON AND SO IS SERVEROUTPUT BTW**

```
create or replace procedure LOGIN_CK_PF
as
fname   bb_shopper.firstname%type;
lname   bb_shopper.lastname%type;
uname   bb_shopper.username%type;
pass    bb_shopper.password%type;


begin

    select firstname, lastname, username, password 
    into fname, lname, uname, pass from bbshop 
    where username=&username;

    if pass = &pass then
    dbms_output.put_line(Sysdate);
    else
    dbms_output.put_line('Invalid Login');
    end if;

exception
    when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('Invalid Login');

end;
/
```

this is what the code output looks like during the entry of values:

```
Enter value for username: 
old  11:  select firstname, lastname, username, 
                 password into fname, lname, uname, pass 
          from bbshop 
new  11:  select firstname, lastname, username, 
                  password into fname, lname, uname, pass 
          from bbshop
```

it looks like its taking the entire select statement as an entry??? **ERRORS FOR THE PARTICULAR LINE IS BELOW:**

```
11/2     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
11/107   PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: Generally, it does not mean that it is taking the whole select as an entry. It shows the piece of code before the bind parameter was attached and after. What is strange in your case that the password column and where clause disappear from your select. And because 3 columns selected into 4 parameters you get this error. Are you sure that this output was produced for the invokation of procedure you have provided in your post? Maybe you made some changes?

Comment: PL/SQL has no facilities for accepting user input. Are you using SQL*Plus to run your script?

Comment: I am indeed using sql plus..but its weird because I've used the same program for other codes with user input and those worked fine.

Comment: @Guneli the code is still the same I havent changed anything

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proper PL/SQL parameters to pass in to your procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOGIN_CK_PF (P_User   IN VARCHAR2,
                                         P_Pass   IN VARCHAR2)
AS
   fname   bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE;
   lname   bb_shopper.lastname%TYPE;
   uname   bb_shopper.username%TYPE;
   pass    bb_shopper.password%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT firstname, lastname, username, password
     INTO fname, lname, uname, pass
     FROM bbshop
    WHERE username = P_User;

   IF pass = P_Pass THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SYSDATE);
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Invalid Login');
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Invalid Login');
END;
```

/

Comment: this works fine however I need to make it so that way I can enter the username and password myself. The problem is whenever I do "&username" it doesnt let me input it in instead it processes it like the value has already been inputted and skips to the password input part.

Comment: Im using sql plus if it helps

Comment: You enter it in sqlplus and pass the values as parameters to the procedure call.  PL/SQL runs on the server, not the client, and has no U/I component.  Please read the documentation if you have further questions.